# how to open multiple url's in multiple browsers using VBscript (like multithreading)

Tags: vbscript

Is multithreading possible using vbscript. i have to form fill a web page in multiple browsers/tabs, so that, i hope can reduce the completion time. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Vbscript does not natively have any methods for launching separate threads although if you try then it's more of "emulation" of multi-threading than anything else

You can check this [documentation](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/vbscript/how-to-multi-thread-vbscript-scripts)

To open a url in vbscript you can try something like this:-

```
  set wShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  wShell.Open "C:\temp\abc.txt"
```